# to export the data of a table in excel and to make graphs on Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am debutant with the framework ruby ​​on rails and I wanted to export the data of a table in excel then to make graphs according to these data.

I have two tables (project and trackers) in the database and a third table (projects_trackers) that stores the primary keys of the other two tables and I want to export the trackers group by project. here are the tables
your help will be welcome thank you

[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! See also: [ask] In addition: In general it is better to include data samples as formatted text, not as images.

Comment: This gem will do what you want but without showing us what you've tried we can't help you.  https://github.com/straydogstudio/axlsx_rails